# PHP/yii query throws SQLSTATE[3F000]: Invalid schema name: 7 ERROR: schema "t" does not exist

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

I have a postgresql query

```
select to_char(date, 'YYYY-mm-dd')
from test
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY-mm-dd')
```

That need to be translated into php/yii

```
public function getDate() {
    return Test::find()->alias('t')
      ->select('to_char(t.date \'YYYY-mm-dd\')')
      ->groupBy('to_char(t.date \'YYYY-mm-dd\')')
      ->asArray()
      ->all();
}
```

But it throws an error that 't' alias does not exist. There is no any issue when I dont use to_char, so I guess PHP might not like it. I dont stick to use to_char I just need to group the dates by day, so if there is any other solution, I would be glad to see.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the query build, see below the correct query:

```
return Test::find()->alias('t')
    ->select(['to_char(t.date, \'YYYY-mm-dd\') as date'])
    ->groupBy(['to_char(t.date, \'YYYY-mm-dd\')'])
    ->asArray()
    ->all();
```